# Почему дублируются пункты меню в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

.top_menu.php(Если переименовать данный файл, то менюшка не выводится) 
Код

```html
<?
$aMenuLinks = Array(
   Array(
      "Главная", 
      "/", 
      Array(), 
      Array(), 
      "" 
   ),
   Array(
      "Каталог", 
      "/catalog/", 
      Array(), 
      Array(), 
      "" 
   ),
   Array(
      "Новости магазина", 
      "/news/", 
      Array(), 
      Array(), 
      "" 
   ),
   Array(
      "Терапия", 
      "/treatments/", 
      Array(), 
      Array(), 
      "" 
   ),
   Array(
      "Спа", 
      "/spa/", 
      Array(), 
      Array(), 
      "" 
   ),
   Array(
      "Контакты", 
      "/contacts/", 
      Array(), 
      Array(), 
      "" 
   )
);
?>
```

Вызов компоненты происходит в header.

```html
       <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "top_menu", array(
               "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
               "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
               "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
               "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "N",
               "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => array(
               ),
               "MAX_LEVEL" => "2",
               "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
               "USE_EXT" => "N",
               "DELAY" => "N",
               "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N"
               ),
               false
               );?>
```

cам template.php.

```html
Код
      <?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);

if (empty($arResult))
   return;
?>

<nav class="bj-top-nav">
<?foreach($arResult as $itemIdex => $arItem):?>
   --<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
<?endforeach;?>
</nav>
```

В шаблоне компонента нет result_modifier.php

ВЫВОДИТсЯ: 
Код

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Главная
            [LINK] => /
            [SELECTED] => 1
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 0
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
            [IS_PARENT] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Главная
            [LINK] => /
            [SELECTED] => 1
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 0
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Каталог
            [LINK] => /catalog/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 1
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Новости магазина
            [LINK] => /news/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 2
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Терапия
            [LINK] => /treatments/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 3
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Спа
            [LINK] => /spa/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 4
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Контакты
            [LINK] => /contacts/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 5
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Каталог
            [LINK] => /catalog/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 1
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Новости магазина
            [LINK] => /news/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 2
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Терапия
            [LINK] => /treatments/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 3
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Спа
            [LINK] => /spa/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 4
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [TEXT] => Контакты
            [LINK] => /contacts/
            [SELECTED] => 
            [PERMISSION] => X
            [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => Array
                (
                )

            [ITEM_TYPE] => D
            [ITEM_INDEX] => 5
            [PARAMS] => Array
                (
                )

            [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
            [IS_PARENT] => 
        )

)
--Главная --Главная --Каталог --Новости магазина --Терапия --Спа --Контакты --Каталог --Новости магазина --Терапия --Спа --Контакты
```

Почему и куда мне копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `"ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top"` и `"CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "top"`, значит где в папке есть еще один `top_menu.php`, DEPTH_LEVEL => 2, это подтверждает